# Cannot convert value '2017-01-26 11:47:54.000000' from column 14 to TIMESTAMP

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, spring, hibernate

*Note: This is not a Duplicate Question.*

I migrated MSSQL database to Mysql database by following [this](http://mysqlworkbench.org/2012/07/migrating-from-ms-sql-server-to-mysql-using-workbench-migration-wizard/) tutorial.

There is a datetime filed say `date_in` in a table say `main`. So when I select `date_in` using mysql query it works fine as below

```
SELECT DATE_IN FROM incoming_audit.main where DATE_IN is not null limit 0, 50000;
```

[image]

In Java - Spring-Hibernate when I try get say first 25 record from the `main` table, It gives me following error

**Error**(Not letting me to paste invalid characters, see image below)

```
Hibernate: select this_.ID as ID1_1_0_, this_.AVAILABLE as AVAILABL2_1_0_, this_.BATTERY as BATTERY3_1_0_, this_.BOX as BOX4_1_0_, this_.CAPS as CAPS5_1_0_, this_.COA_EDITION as COA_EDIT6_1_0_, this_.COA_VERSION as COA_VERS7_1_0_, this_.CPU as CPU8_1_0_, this_.CPU_CORES as CPU_CORE9_1_0_, this_.CPU_DATA_WIDTH as CPU_DAT10_1_0_, this_.CPUSPD as CPUSPD11_1_0_, this_.CUSTOMER_ASSET as CUSTOME12_1_0_, this_.CUSTOMER_ID as CUSTOME13_1_0_, this_.DATE_IN as DATE_IN14_1_0_, this_.DATE_INC as DATE_IN15_1_0_, this_.FORM_FACTOR as FORM_FA16_1_0_, this_.HDD_INC_SERIAL as HDD_INC17_1_0_, this_.HDD_MODEL as HDD_MOD18_1_0_, this_.HDD_SERIAL as HDD_SER19_1_0_, this_.HDD_SIZE as HDD_SIZ20_1_0_, this_.HDD_SMART as HDD_SMA21_1_0_, this_.INC_TECH as INC_TEC22_1_0_, this_.INT_SERIAL as INT_SER23_1_0_, this_.KILLDISK as KILLDIS24_1_0_, this_.LOCATION as LOCATIO25_1_0_, this_.LOT_ID as LOT_ID26_1_0_, this_.MANUFACTURER as MANUFAC27_1_0_, this_.MODEL as MODEL28_1_0_, this_.NOTES as NOTES29_1_0_, this_.PALETTE as PALETTE30_1_0_, this_.PLASTIC_CONDITION as PLASTIC31_1_0_, this_.POWER_ADAPTER as POWER_A32_1_0_, this_.PXE_TECH as PXE_TEC33_1_0_, this_.RAM_PER_SLOT as RAM_PER34_1_0_, this_.RAM_SLOTS as RAM_SLO35_1_0_, this_.SCREEN_CONDITION as SCREEN_36_1_0_, this_.SERIAL as SERIAL37_1_0_, this_.TOTAL_RAM as TOTAL_R38_1_0_, this_.WEBCAM as WEBCAM39_1_0_ from Main this_ limit ?
2017-01-26 11:48:33 [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] WARN   - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: S1009
2017-01-26 11:48:33 [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] ERROR  - Cannot convert value '2017-01-26 11:47:54.000000' from column 14 to TIMESTAMP.
Jan 26, 2017 11:48:33 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [mvc-dispatcher] in context with path [/sts] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query] with root cause
java.lang.NumberFormatException: 81646
SOLDRETAILû
```

[image]

**Column Mapping**

```
@Type(type = "timestamp")
@Column(name = "DATE_IN", nullable = true)
private Date dateIn;
```

How to remove invalid characters ?

**Update**

When I run below query, my code runs perfect

```
UPDATE incoming_audit.main SET DATE_IN=null WHERE DATE_IN is not null;
```

But when I run below query after running above query, again exception of invalid characters is coming

```
UPDATE incoming_audit.main SET DATE_IN=now() WHERE DATE_IN is null;
```

But this time its different exception.

[image]

Comment: did you try it to paste in notepad? or notepad ++

Comment: Yeah I paste it to notepad++, its pasting on the notepad++ with all invalid characters.

Comment: what is the datatype of `DATE_IN`?

Comment: remove the invalid characters then update the error field itself.

Comment: i think that according to hibernate and the JDBC driver `date_in` is not a `timestamp`; try to check on your DB the `date_in` datatype maybe you have to configure hibernate properly

Comment: @MicheleMariotti and its type is DateTime .

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue, for someone looking for options,

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot convert value '2021-04-23 10:43:54.000000' from column 15 to TIMESTAMP.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.7.jar:?]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.7.jar:?]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.7.jar:?]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetRow.getTimestampFast(ResultSetRow.java:1328) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.7.jar:?]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.BufferRow.getTimestampFast(BufferRow.java:573) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.7.jar:?]
```

The data type was `datetime(6)` for this column. The data was added through hibernate and this error came when I tried to load the data.

The column is related last modified timestamp.

```
@Column(
        name = "last_modified_time",
        nullable = false
)
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date lastModifiedTime;
```

As `timestamp` is better suited here, I used `timestamp` data type instead of `datetime(6)` which fixed the issue without any other modifications required.